# Are there any files in /proc which reading them have side effects?

Tags: linux, grep, kernel, system-calls

I want to run this command:

`grep -r <some pattern> /proc`

but since reading files in /proc may result in syscalls، as a precaution I want to be sure that reading (all of) them
does not have any (dangerous) side effects on kernel.

Comment: While your question is understandable as it is, the phrase "since reading files in `/proc` may result in syscalls" is not quite correct. **Accessing every file results in syscalls**: `open()`, `read()`/`write()`, and so on. This is common for all files, be they regular ones or ones under `/proc`, `/sys` and other special filesystems. The difference is a (kernel) code, executing during these syscalls. But you are right in that reading `/proc` files involves some specific code execution

Answer (score 1):

I have recently read this article about /proc and I think it is very useful and interesting: [Making good use of the files in /proc](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3227929/linux/making-good-use-of-the-files-in-proc.html).

As far as I know I can tell you that reading that files wouldn't cause any problem. They represents Linux/Unix statistics and processes.